# How do you run Classes from an external file from the functions.php in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, function

How do you run Classes from an external file from the functions.php?

I'm using WordPress and the Beaver Builder plugin. I have a pagination list with info from the WP db. This is on a page using a search template (search.php). It includes a file (get-jobs.php). In order to see the results, I have to use a PHP Snippet plugin to set a global variable on the page that recognizes the $result variable provided by get-jobs.php, as I use the built-in modules to layout the page.

This works so far. I can see my formatted results.

When the pagination button is clicked, a function is called from my js file(custom-script.js) to update the results.

```
function selectJobs() {
    $.ajax({
        url: site_url + '/get-jobs.php', 
        type: "GET",
        data: {
          ajax': '1',
            'state': GetURLParameter('country'),
            'limit': GetURLParameter('limit')
        },
        success:function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
          console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    }); 
}
```

This doesn't work and I received a 403(Forbidden) error. I changed it to this:

```
function selectJobs(country) {
    var country = country;
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          'action':'country_ajax_request',
          'country' : country
        },
        success:function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
          console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    }); 
}
```

...which got rid of the error, and submitted the request.

In my functions.php, I have this:

```
function country_ajax_request() {
   //include_once( get_stylesheet_directory() .'/get-jobs.php');

   MY FUNCTIONS GO HERE
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_country_ajax_request', 'country_ajax_request' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_country_ajax_request', 'country_ajax_request' );
```

Here's an bit of what's in get-jobs.php:

```
<?php

$get = (!empty($get) ? $get : $_REQUEST);

if(isset($get['ajax']) && $get['ajax'] == 1) {
  require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php');
}

class GetJobs {

    private $wpdb;

    public function __construct($input) {
        global $wpdb;
        $this->wpdb = $wpdb;
        $this->tableName = $this->wpdb->prefix . 'job_postings';
        $this->country = (!empty($input['country']) ? $input['country'] : '');
        $this->page = (!empty($input['page']) ? $input['page'] : '');
        $this->limit = (!empty($input['limit']) ? $input['limit'] : 10);
    }

    public function getLocations() {
        $result = [];
        $states = $this->wpdb->get_results("SELECT country FROM " . $this->tableName . " WHERE deleted_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'");

        foreach ($country as $key=>$row) {
            $result[$row->country] = $row->country;
        }

        return $result;
    }
    
    // almost 200 more lines of this
}

$get['page'] = (!empty($get['page']) ? $get['page'] : 1);

$jobs = new GetJobs($get);

$query = $jobs->getQuery();

$jobsQuery = $jobs->getJobsQuery($query,(!empty($get['limit']) ? $get['limit'] : $jobs->limit));

$result['postings'] = $jobs->formatPostings($jobsQuery);

if(isset($get['ajax']) && $get['ajax'] == 1){
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

I tried to include the file, but that didn't work. It pulled data, but didn't seem go through the functions.

I want to reuse the existing file to perform the update list task. I don't want to rewrite get-jobs.php, if possible. I've used this same code just fine on other projects. Just not with this plugin.

Any thoughts or assistance as how I can approach this problem is appreciated.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I took another look at that include. It is pulling data. However, it's generates a json file, following by all of the html. The HTML is malformed. Here's what the beginning looks like:

```
<div id="postings" style="display: block;">{"states":{"AB":"AB","AZ":"AZ","BC":"BC","CA":"CA","FL":"FL","GA":"GA","IL":"IL","KS":"KS","NC":"NC","NS":"NS","ON":"ON","PA":"PA","QC":"QC","WA":"WA"},"category":{"":"","Accounting":"Accounting","Customs":"Customs","Finance":"Finance","Human Resources":"Human Resources","IT":"IT","Information Technology":"Information Technology","International":"International","Marketing":"Marketing","Marketing and Communications":"Marketing and Communications","Operations":"Operations","Project Management":"Project Management","Reception":"Reception","Sales":"Sales","Warehouse":"Warehouse"},"postings":"<a href="\&quot;\/career?jid=job_20200827220600_9WZICSJNQ2XVDB1N\&quot;">\n\t\t\t\t\t</a>
```

Comment: Is this just a typo? (...request2) ```function country_ajax_request2() {
   //include_once( get_stylesheet_directory() .'/get-jobs.php');

   MY FUNCTIONS GO HERE
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_country_ajax_request', 'country_ajax_request' );```

Comment: Oops. Yes, that was a typo.

Comment: Note that ```$jobs->getQuery()``` and ```$jobs->getJobsQuery``` and ```$jobs->formatPostings``` are not defined in your class. You should get an error.